# How can I access current Code Coverage Value in gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: laravel, gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-coverage

I'm trying to run jobs if my code coverage exceeds 80%.

I have a laravel(10.x) project and I successfully generated code coverage of my and [project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp19y.png)

Here is my code coverage calculated.
[Code Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tOx0.png)

Now I cannot access this code coverage in bash. need some help

I successfully calculated code coverage in GitLab-pipeline. But I'm not able to store this in a variable

Comment: Could [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing#enforcing-a-minimum-coverage-threshold) help you? This doesn't give you the coverage value but it should fail if the threshold isn't met.

Comment: This works for me. and also I store this in a variable using regular expression and grep.